# Algorithm to detect if a pixel is within a boundary

Tags: c#, silverlight, algorithm, image, image-processing

We're currently creating a simple application for **image manipulation** in Silverlight, and we've hit a bit of a snag. We want users to be able to select an area of an image (either by drawing a freehand line around their chosen area or by creating a polygon around it), and then be able to apply effects to the pixels within that selection.

Creating a selection of images is easy enough, but we want a really fast algorithm for deciding which pixels should be manipulated (ie. **something to detect which pixels are within the user's selection**).

We've thought of three possibilities so far, but we're sure that there must be a really efficient and quick way of doing this that's better than these.

**1. Pixel by pixel.**
We just go through every pixel in an image and check whether it's within the user selection. Obviously this is far too slow!

**2. Using a Line Crossing Algorithim.**
The type of thing [seen here](http://bcu.copsewood.net/dsalg/linecross/line_geometry.html).

**3. Flood Fill.**
Select the pixels along the path of the selection and then perform a flood fill within that selection. This might work fine.

This must a problem that's commonly solved, so we're guessing there's a ton more solutions that we've not even thought of.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Do you want something faster than O(n) ? Is a smart Flood Fill really that slow?

Comment: Are you sure this is really a performance issue? I mean, even ms paint does this kind of thing pretty fast (drawing a closed polygon filled, which is pretty much what you need).

Comment: You should take a look at http://nokola.com/blog/?tag=/EasyPainter

Comment: @Django : Could you please share the code ?? I am in a same situation like you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flood fill algorithm is a good choice.

Take a look at this implementation:

[Queue-Linear Flood Fill: A Fast Flood Fill Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/queuelinearfloodfill.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use your polygon to create a clipping path. The mini-language for describing polygons for Silverlight is quiet well documented.

Alter the pixels on a copy of your image (*all pixels* is usually easy to modify than *some pixels*), then use the clipping path to render only the desired area of the changes back to the original image (probably using an extra buffer bitmap for the result).

*Hope this helps. Just throwing the ideas out and see if any stick :)*